# Error al crear un objeto

Tags: java, poo

soy nueva en eso de aprender a programar en Java y me gustaría saber ¿por que me aparece un error al crear un nuevo objeto en el main?

```
  public class Ecuacion{
    private double a,b,c;
    private double x1,x2;
    private double part_1, part_2;
    private double resultado_r, resultado_i;

    public Ecuacion(double a, double b, double c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    public Ecuacion(double x1, double x2,){
       x1 = 0;
       x2 = 0;
    }

    public double x(){
        part_1 = (-b/(2*a));
        return part_1;
    }     

    public double discriminante(){
        part_2 = ((b*b)-(4*a*c))/(2*a);
        return part_2;
    }


    public double real(){
        resultado_r = Math.sqrt(part_2);
        resultado_r = Math.round(resultado_r*100)/100d;
        return resultado_r;
    }

    public double imaginario(){
        resultado_i = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(part_2));
        resultado_i = Math.round(resultado_i*100)/100d;
        return resultado_i;
    }

    public double getA (){ return a;}
    public double getB (){ return b;}
    public double getC (){ return c;}

    public void setX1(double x1){
        x();

        if(part_1<0){
            imaginario();
            x1 = part_1 + resultado_i;
            System.out.println(x1 + "i");
        }
        else if (part_1>0){
            real();
            x1 = part_1 + resultado_r;
        }
        else{
            x1 = part_1;
        }
    }

    public void setX2(double x2){
        x();

        if(part_1<0){
            imaginario();
            x2 = part_1 + resultado_i;
            System.out.println(x2 + "i");
        }
        else if (part_1>0){
            real();
            x2 = part_1 + resultado_r;
        }
        else{
            x2 = part_1;
        }
    }
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x1=0, x2=0;
    Ecuacion e1 = new Ecuacion (x1,x2);
    System.out.println("Valor de a:" + e1.getA());
    System.out.println("Valor de b:" + e1.getB());
    System.out.println("Valor de c:" + e1.getC());

    e1.setX1(x1);
    e1.setX2(x2);
}
```

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]. Que error te aparece? uno de los constructores esta mal, para que le pasas los parametros x1 y x2 si no haces nada con ellos, porque inmediatamente le asignas x1 = 0? y dentro del setX1, que quiere decir x()?

Comment: En el constructor de `public Ecuacion(double x1, double x2,){
       x1 = 0;
       x2 = 0;
    }` yo pondría `public Ecuacion(double x1, double x2,){
       this.x1 = x1;
       this.x2 = x2;
    }`

Comment: Respecto de los constructores, me parece que x1 y x2 son valores que se calculan internamente a partir de a,b, y c por lo que no sería necesario el constructor (que lleva x1 y x2). Luego fijate que parete importante de tu programa se resuelve en `discriminante()` y el método no se llama desde ningún lado. Y para tener en cuenta tenés una división por `a`, por lo que deberías controlar que no sea cero (no sería una cuadrática en ese caso pero el programa no lo sabe).